# How to change confinement without reinstalling?

Tags: snap, lxd, gitlab

I recently installed snap lxd in one of my servers. Initially it was working fine. Now I needed to install gitlab-ce on my lxd container which requires sysctl access. But snap documentation saying I only can change confinement option at install time. Is there any way to change confinement without reinstalling it because other containers already running production websites.

Update.

It turned out problem is not related to snap confinement. Same "Read only file system" error happening on apt lxd.

Tried versions

```
ubuntu 20.04 with snap lxd 4.0.4, gitlab-ce 13.8
ubuntu 16.04 with apt lxd 3.0.3, gitlab-ce 13.8
```

Both containers are `security.privileged=true` If I use `security.privileged=false` I will receive worse error logs.

Also tried gitlab recommended sysctl config on host.

```
kernel.sem = 250 32000 32 262
kernel.shmall = 4194304
kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
net.core.somaxconn = 1024
```

Error Log:

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

Multiple failures occurred:
* Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed occurred in Chef Infra Client run: gitlab_sysctl[kernel.sem] (postgresql::enable line 71) had an 
error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[load sysctl conf kernel.sem] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/packag
e/resources/gitlab_sysctl.rb line 48) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but receive
d '255'
---- Begin output of sysctl -e -p /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: sysctl: setting key "kernel.sem": Read-only file system
---- End output of sysctl -e -p /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf ----
Ran sysctl -e -p /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf returned 255
* Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed occurred in delayed notification: execute[reload all sysctl conf] (package::sysctl line 18) had a
n error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '255'
---- Begin output of sysctl -e --system ----
STDOUT: * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-link-restrictions.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf ...
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
net.ipv4.conf.default.promote_secondaries = 1
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0 2147483647
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-pid-max.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-cloudimg-ipv6.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/protect-links.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
STDERR: sysctl: setting key "kernel.printk": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "kernel.kptr_restrict": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "fs.protected_hardlinks": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "fs.protected_symlinks": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "kernel.sysrq": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "kernel.yama.ptrace_scope": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "vm.mmap_min_addr": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries": Invalid argument
sysctl: setting key "fs.protected_regular": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "fs.protected_fifos": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "kernel.pid_max": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "kernel.sem": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "kernel.shmall": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "kernel.shmmax": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "fs.protected_fifos": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "fs.protected_hardlinks": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "fs.protected_regular": Read-only file system
sysctl: setting key "fs.protected_symlinks": Read-only file system
---- End output of sysctl -e --system ----
Ran sysctl -e --system returned 255
```

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: @David I'm pretty sure this will happen any supported ubuntu, snap and lxd versions. Because this is not a bug. This is snap's feature. I'm asking method to disable this feature called strict confinement. In other word enabling `--devmode` flag.

Comment: @user535733 thank you for link but it is not about gitlab runner. Althought if if lxd was apt version I would fix this issue easily using instruction from gitlab issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot change kernel parameters from within the container, you can set these values on the host and they will be usable in the container.
Then, it is up to the gitlab installer that does not attempt to set them if it finds that they already have the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

When you change security.privileged on a container it doesn't come into effect until the container is restarted.

No need to rebuild the container..

lxc restart  will do